# Finding the matrix of orthogonal Projection

Tags: linear-algebra

I am really confused by how to find the matrix of the orthogonal projection. Here is the textbook problem:

> Question. Find the matrix of the orthogonal projection in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ onto the line $x_1 = -2x_2$.

Comment: How do you find the matrix for any linear transformation? You look at what the transformation does to the standard basis vectors. So figure that out. (Unless you know fancier stuff. But we can't tell when you just post a homework problem with absolutely no effort or explanation of what you're learning at the time.)

Comment: Refer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515612/question-about-the-matrix-of-linear-transformation/3515764#3515764

Comment: This isn't different from the usual problems of finding matrix representations of linear operators. Find an orthonormal basis for the projected subspace $V=\{x_1=-2x_2\}$. Find an orthonormal basis for $V^\perp$. Put the basis vectors of the two subspaces to form a real orthogonal matrix $U$. The required matrix is then $U\pmatrix{1\\ &0}U^{-1}=U\pmatrix{1\\ &0}U^T$.

Comment: It follows that in practice there is no need to find any basis for $V^\perp$. If $U_1$ is a rectangular matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis of $V$, then the required matrix is $U_1U_1^T$. In your case, since $V$ is one-dimensional, if $u$ is a unit vector that spans $V$, then the required matrix is $uu^T$.

Comment: To project onto a one dimensional subspace you find a unit column vector $u$ that spans the subspace then the matrix $P=uu^T$ where $u^T$ is the transpose of $u$ is the orthogonal projection onto that subspace. Can you take it from there?